# Library or libraries to qr codes and bar codes

Tags: android

I am searching a lot about library to bar codes and qr codes, but I can't find good library to both. I need library which I can use to qr codes and bar codes. I find zxing but when tablet has no focus codes are not scanned. Which library or libraries you prefer? I can use two other libraries.

Comment: I've used zxing in two projects and it works perfectly on phones and tables scanning QR-codes and Code39 barcodes. One of devices I've tested was cheap China tablet with weak camera - it also work on them.

Comment: I will try, but someone tell me that samsung galaxy tab 2 has problem with that library and properly scaning